# how to integrate facebook login into a cordova based app

Tags: android, facebook, cordova

I am having trouble configuring FB login to work with my cordova mobile application. 
I have followed this tutorial: https://github.com/jeduan/cordova-plugin-facebook4

This is login code:

```
var fbLoginSuccess = function (userData) {
  console.log("UserInfo: ", userData);
}

facebookConnectPlugin.login(["public_profile"], fbLoginSuccess,
   function loginError (error) {
     console.error(error)
   }
);
```

The button is visible but performs no action when clicked.

```
 <ion-app>
    <a href="javascript:void();" onclick="login()" id="fbLink" >Login with Facebook</a>
 </ion-app>
```

Comment: where is your "login" function?

Comment: login() {
        facebookConnectPlugin.login(['email'], function(response) {
            alert('Logged in');
            alert(JSON.stringify(response.authResponse));
        }, function(error){
            alert(error);
        })
    }

Comment: put an alert/console.log BEFORE the facebookConnectPlugin call and see if the login function even gets called.

Comment: Can you give me the code?

Comment: you really need me to give you the code for the simple task of putting an alert in a function?